# HTML: div floats are not horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that I've placed inside another div:

```
<div id="outer_div">
    <div id="left_div">
        <!-- Buttons and text field -->
    </div>
    <div id="right_div">
        <!-- Buttons and drop list -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My style sheet includes the following:

```
#left_div {
    float:left;
}
#right_div {
    float:right;
}
```

Now, when I do this, I expect that the left and right div will be on the left and right of the screen, respectively, and that they will be aligned horizontally as well. The first holds true, however, the second hope is not true. If I put left_div above right_div, the right_div buttons and drop list are on a line below the left_div. If I put right_div above left_div, the divs are almost in line, but the right div is slightly elevated, so that it overlaps a div that is above it.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, the question is impossible to answer until we see what you are actually doing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cMhpK/ here is a sample?

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine to me. Are you saying that the right div is not in line with the yellow parent div?

Comment: that is my fiddle.... not the OP

Comment: The fiddle doesn't have the same issue I'm having, and I can't replicate it on a fiddle for some reason.

Comment: Ok, new development from looking at the css and html through "inspect element" in the browser. The div is being shifted, I believe, due to the first element being the droplist, which is not as large as the buttons. So the top of the droplist is aligned with the top of the div, but the buttons then stick out above the top of it. Not sure why this is the case.

The buttons are tagged as div blocks as well, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width to your `outer_div`

```
#outer_div {
    width: 100%; //or whatever width you would like it to be
}

#left_div, #right_div {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample that works fine for me.

```
<div id="outer_div">
    <div id="left_div">
        <div class="button"></div>
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_div">
        <div class="button"></div>
        <div class="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
#outer_div
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 450px;
    background: yellow;
}

#left_div {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: thin red solid;
}
#right_div {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: thin blue solid;
}

.button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: thin green solid;
}
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cMhpK/

Comment: I didn't do anything with the buttons in the inner div blocks, but they're all inline rather than being stacked.

Comment: i don't understand your comment/question? Can you please re-phrase?

Comment: I thought the default for div blocks was to be aligned vertically against the left edge of the window/parent div. However, I didn't make any styling changes to the inner div blocks, and rather than appearing vertically stacked and left aligned, they instead are on the same line.

Comment: please visit : www.jsfiddle.com, then create what you are trying to explain. you have to show us the code that you are writing - there are a multitude of issues that could affect this, and simply TALKING wont help. We need to see code